# Copying databases to remote locations

Tags: database, vpn, point-of-sale, file-sharing

Our EPOS system copies data by compressing the database into a zip file, and manually copying to each till, using shared directories.

Each branched is liked to the main location, using VPN which can be problematic, but is required for the file sharing to work correctly.

Since our database system currently does not support replication, is there another solution for copying data or should we migrate our software to another database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replication is the "right" way to go, so if migrating to another database is an option (is it really?), that's the best route.

You might consider a utility that queries all the tables for raw data (in CSV?), sending that to files.  Then at least you don't have to take the database down to do the backup.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll leave the code alone for now and consider a new database engine for the next major version.  Changing now would involve retesting everything.